# Errors when importing with pip due to PYTHONPATH on ubuntu server

Tags: python, environment-variables

I've been following [this](http://bathompso.com/blog/Flask-AWS-Setup/) tutorial and it states that

> The $PYTHONPATH variable seems to get unset randomly, and causes errors for later steps.

and then to add the following to `~/.bashrc`:

```
export PYTHONPATH='/usr/lib/python2.7:/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk:/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old:/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat'
```

I did this and then tried to install a bunch of pip packages with `pip install -r requirements.txt`

I get a load of errors when installing all the packages, this can be seen [here](http://pastebin.com/sBYVnusE).

I think this relates to the issue with PYTHONPATH. Why do I receive this error and what can be done so that I get no errors when using python and pip? Thanks.

---

**Edit:**

I've checked other tutorials for setting up Flask with Ubuntu and none have stated changing `PYTHONPATH`. I followed [this tutorial](https://realpython.com/blog/python/kickstarting-flask-on-ubuntu-setup-and-deployment/) and tried installing packages in a virtualenv but I get errors. I tried installing a package called python-bcrypt but get this in the terminal:

```
bcrypt/bcrypt_python.c:17:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

 #include "Python.h"

                    ^

compilation terminated.

error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I tried installing pycrypto and got the same:

```
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -std=c99 -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -Isrc/ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/MD2.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/MD2.o

src/MD2.c:31:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

 #include "Python.h"

                    ^

compilation terminated.

error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Is there any reasons for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Installing the Python development library solved this for me (found from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21530768/733547).

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev  # for python2.x installs
sudo apt-get install python3-dev  # for python3.x installs
```

Comment: Indeed, the linked post is not particularly similar, which is why this issue was a pain to fix. I'm hoping that by posting my solution here, it will bridge that gap and help anyone else that stumbles across it and is dealing with the same issue. I suppose you can flag it if you like, but I had the exact same error message as OP while performing the exact same action and performing the above steps resolved it.

Answer (score 1):

"Get unset randomly"? No.

The `PYTHONPATH` environment variable is set by a process (probably running `bash`). If `PYTHONPATH` is `export`ed, a copy of `PYTHONPATH` is passed to any processes started by this one (or any they start).

If some child process destroys `PYTHONPATH` via:

```
unset PYTHONPATH
```

or

```
PYTHONPATH=
```

then the bad `PYTHONPATH` is visible only to the process that destroyed it, and any processes that process (or its children) subsequently starts.

Eventually, as child processes finish and exit, the process with the bad `PYTHONPATH` will exit, and the (bad) definition it had for `PYTHONPATH` will go away as well.

The process that started the child that destroyed `PYTHONPATH` will have the UNdestroyed definition, and always will have had it.

I would suspect that "this tutorial" lacks Linux understanding, and might be dangerous.

Your `PYTHONPATH` contains the following directories:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat
```

Ask yourself the following questions, for EACH directory in $PYTHONPATH:

Does it exist on my system, and do the permissions say I can access it?

```
/bin/ls -ld $(echo "$PYTHONPATH" | tr ":" " ")
```

Can I access the files within the directory?

```
/bin/ls -l $(echo "$PYTHONPATH" | tr ":" " ")
```

Does this directory contain files that Python, or the Python programs or whatever you want to run needs, and accesses through `$PYTHONPATH`.

Looking at the FIRST error (not warning, not info, but "error") message, one sees:

```
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_ubuntu/MySQL-python/setup.py) egg_info for package MySQL-python
    sh: 1: mysql_config: not found
```

Searching [manpages.ubuntu.com](http://manpages.ubuntu.com) for `msql_config` produces:

```
trusty (1) mysql_config.1.gz
Provided by: libmariadbclient-dev_5.5.36-1_i386 

NAME
       mysql_config - get compile options for compiling clients

SYNOPSIS
       mysql_config options

DESCRIPTION
       mysql_config provides you with useful information for compiling your
       MySQL client and connecting it to MySQL.
```

This means you have NOT successfully installed and configured `MySQL` or a `MySQL client`, and whatever "this tutorial" is trying to get you to do requires `MySQL`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I still don't understand how to fix this problem. I have another package which imports the regex library but cannot import it as it cannot find it. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using, that has no `regex` library? Search online for "How do I set up MySQL".

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 12.04. Python automatically has the regex library so the most likely reason the package cannot import the regex library is due to the `PYTHONPATH`

Comment: Sorry I"m using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: You do not seem to have read the answer, nor checked the things I told you to check.  I suspect that you have not installed some packages required by the tutorial. Which parts of my answer need more explanation? Do not ask a new question in these comments.

Comment: Apologies. I've read through your answer and I need most of the directories in `PYTHONPATH`. I'll update the question to further explain the problem.